# Are there any translations available from the Gandharan Buddhist Texts? When will they be available?

Tags: texts, tipitaka

Please find reference for the texts: 
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandhāran_Buddhist_texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandh%C4%81ran_Buddhist_texts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like these ones?

- https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Gandhari
- https://www.thriftbooks.com/a/richard-salomon/877720
- http://www.rhinoresourcecenter.com/pdf_files/138/1386654811.pdf

Amazon lists 3 pages of books. I didn't check all three pages though.
But it should be enough to get you started.

Have fun. :)